# How to lock combobox in c#, winForm when is loading?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm loading the Comboboxes only when the client need them.
But when I'm loading the Comboboxes it's looks bad...

The code:

```
 combobox1.SetBindingToLookup(dataSource);
```

The type of `dataSource` is `IEnumerable<T>`
and this code action when the client click on the combobox

I'm think that the solution for this is to lock the combobox when the client click on it and only when loading finish to unlock it.

Comment: looks bad? means ? you are loading `combobox` when client clicks on `combobox` ? meaning at first they were empty?

Comment: Yes at first they were empty, I meen that when I click on it it's looks like - open the combobox empty and then looks like refresh the combobox and after it's loading I'm need to click again to see the data

Comment: it is because you are not loading combobox properly. if you load it on click, your first click will be wasted because it will do loading only (not open options).. you can load it earlier, just dont set selected index. it will look empty at first, but when you click on it, it will have options

Comment: what you meen when you say (write) "you can load it earlier"' which event? I whant when the client need it. and he need it only when he click on the combobox

Comment: load event of form

Comment: no. I'm loading on this event to many things and the form loading to sloaly. so the solution tha I foaund is to load the comboboxes only when the client need them! and he need this data when he click to select some item from the combobox

Comment: okay, got it. let me see what can be done in this situation, btw when event you are using to load it.? click?

Comment: How long does the loading takes ? Maybe you can load the combobox in a seperate thread so the form can load normal and the combobox will be ready after 1 or 2 seconds depending on how long it takes in your case

Comment: Thanx, yes I whant to load the data only when the client click on the combobox.

Comment: @GuidoG - It's take a few seconds (1-0.5) but it's looks bad almost it's so some seconds. and how can I do it in a second thred???

Comment: @Ayal 1-0.5 seconds is huge amount of time! how many items are you loading on combo box ?

Comment: @Amit - It's took from the DataBase it going to the server and then go back with all the data. It's about 8106 items

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per discussion in question's comment. You don't want your combox to load on Load event of form and neither you want to load it in thread.

And basic requirement is not to have flickering effect (which you have as on click event itself you are loading combobox - so combobox will be seen first empty and then loaded).

The best thing you can do is to change an event where you are loading your combobox. Event should be such which does raise before click event, so when user click on it, combobox would have been loaded.

let's say, `MouseEnter` event of combobox. While going to click on it, user must enter mouse on combobox first, at that time this event will be raised, you can load your combobox there.

like below:

```
private void combobox1_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    combobox1.Items.Clear();
    combobox1.SetBindingToLookup(dataSource);
    //for (int i = 0; i < options.Count(); i++)
    //{
    //    comboBox1.Items.Add(options[i]);
    //}
}
```

Note: this event will be raised if user has hover mouse (even when by mistake), but as all those cases will be done after loading form. Overall performance will not affect.

---

other possible event is `DropDown` event as BaskarJohn has suggested in comments below.

by using that event you can load combobox by both ways (mouse click and keyboard interaction).

```
private void comboBox1_DropDown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    combobox1.Items.Clear();
    combobox1.SetBindingToLookup(dataSource);
}
```

only thing you may face, it will be little slow (as you mentioned in comments of question that loading takes 0.5 - 1 seconds) in opening `dropdown`

Comment: But I can to loading it with my way? whit function `combobox1.SetBindingToLookup(dataSource);` ??

Comment: yes of course .. however you are loading it.. you can do it here.

Comment: OK, and what you meen 'only with mouse', if the client will click on it with keyboard this event not be rais?

Comment: no! i afraid it will not. is there such requirement too ? because in question i read 'click' only

Comment: I'm try now what tha you write to me. But when I move only with the mouse on the combobox it's load it.

Comment: using DropDown event you can solve this. only you need to manage every drop down.

Comment: The code: `private void combobox1_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                combobox1.Items.Clear();
    combobox1.SetBindingToLookup(dataSource);
        }`

Comment: @BaskarJohn nice suggestion (i will add that in question too), but only problem is that, it is not that smooth as mouse enter is.

Comment: @Ayal what I meen ? I'm sorry but i did not get you

Comment: @Amit you write: 'but only problem is that, it is not that smooth as mouse enter is'

Comment: @Ayal i said that because `MouseEnter` event raises first then `DropDown` event raises. thus `MouseEnter` gets more time to load combobox and it results smooth user interface. while `DropDown` event raises later, so it freezes UI little. But `DropDown` event has other benefits which `MouseEnter` doesn't have.

Comment: I'm whant to give you feadback-Votes but I'm can't

Comment: @Ayal you will need some reputation for that. :) keep visiting here and contribute your knowledge to help people in best level. if you understood, that's enough for me.!

Comment: @Amit how I got reputation?

Comment: ask good question (here good is - you must have put some effort on researching on that, this question should be helpful to other people, it should be clearly written) and answer properly on other people's question to help them and also by accepting most suitable answer on your question

Comment: @Ayal if this answer helped you, you should mark it as an answer so other people with similar problem can have benefit of it.

Comment: @Amit - can I ask anothe question?: Why I see "-1" near my question?

Answer (score 1):

You can load data in an async method. Then you can simply load data in `Load` event of the form, or if you like lazy-load them in `DropDown` event of the combo box by calling `LoadComboBoxData()`.

For example:

```
private async Task LoadComboBoxData()
{
    if (comboBox1.DataSource == null)
    {
        comboBox1.DataSource = new List<string> { "Loading ..." };
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            //Let's say you load items from a source and it's time consuming,
            //Just for example
            Thread.Sleep(3000);
            comboBox1.DataSource = Enumerable.Range(1, 10000)
                .Select(x => new { Name = x, Value = x }).ToList(); ;
        });
        comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Name";
        comboBox1.ValueMember = "Value";
    }
}
```

Comment: This way, even if you put loading data in `Load` event of the form, the form will be shown without any delay. It also shows a message in the `ComboBox` which shows it's loading.

Answer (score 0):

I have a small approach to handle this situation.

```
public partial class FormComboBoxBinding : Form
{
    DataTable dt;
    public FormComboBoxBinding()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        comboBox1.LazyBind = LoadBind;
    }

    private void LoadBind()
    {
        if (dt == null)
        {
            dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("messages", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("c_id", typeof(int));

            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                dt.Rows.Add("message " + i.ToString(), i);
            }
            comboBox1.DataSource = dt.DefaultView;
            comboBox1.DisplayMember = "messages";
            comboBox1.ValueMember = "c_id";
        }
    }
}

public class ComboBoxEx : ComboBox
{
    public Action LazyBind { get; set; }
    protected override void OnClick(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnClick(e);
    }

    protected override void OnDropDown(EventArgs e)
    {
        if (LazyBind != null) LazyBind();
        base.OnDropDown(e);
    }
}
```

You can customise yourself.

Comment: aah you have added an answer too! should i remove `dropdown` part from my answer ?